# How to import a lot of contacts (above 5000)

Tags: import

I need to import a file with individuals (round 5000) and organizations (round 2000), relationships between them and all of them being added to group.

What would you advice: api import? front-end with server settings to optimize time-outs? SQL injection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing, I ended up using the [api csv import](https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui) extension. Not perfect but at least helped me do the job.

Answer (score 5):

In the very short term, the [advimport](https://civicrm.org/extensions/advanced-import) extension might help: it adds a button to the core contact import to "process with advimport", and it uses its queue for processing. A bit slower, but it won't crash.

In the long term, this is something that a few folks such as Eileen and Tim have been working on improving in core, so hopefully somewhere around CiviCRM 5.51 or 5.52, core import should be much more efficient ([PR#23669](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23669), for example). There are a few [open PRs](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pulls) waiting review, if you are interested to help speed things up.

Comment: definitely worth giving a try! thanks Mathieu